# Installing Mysql Workbench in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I install preferably the latest version of MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: This question is not directly related to Ubuntu. It seems the Workbench is only supported on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10. so it'll be better to ask MySQL for support of an older version of Ubuntu (very unlikely) or update to Ubuntu 16.04. You can always try to install the packages on their site but you might a lot of errors

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://www.devopsservice.com/install-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-centos-6/.

1. Download the repository using `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb`.
2. Install it with `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb`
3. Update the apt packages by runnung `sudo apt update -y`.
4. Install with `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community -y`
5. During the setup, select `workbench`, version `6.3` and then `apply` to finish the installer.